# I want to create mail service like mailchimp in nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, mailchimp, mail-server, bulk-email

I want to create mail service like mailchimp, but via google mail services I am able to send the mail with one email Id only but my purpose is to create bulk email service with the individuals email ID who register over the system.

We have tried with google mail services but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I've been there and hope this helps you.
[google](/questions/tagged/google) doesn't offer promotional or transactional `SMTP` services. You could use your daily personal quota.

> But it's limited to 20 per hour. For google workspace limits, visit [`Gmail limits and policies`](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)

So you gonna need to host your own `SMTP` server or use services like `MailChimp`.

If you gonna host Your `SMTP` server and has no knowledge about how things work. Start with services like `cyber panel` to easily set up the server.

use `Nodemailer` npm package to handle mail. [`documentation`](https://nodemailer.com/about/)

```
npm i nodemailer
```